# PHP regex capture template tags and if statement tags

Tags: php, regex

I have tags in a html file like this, placed throughout;

```
*|SUBJECT|*
*|SUBJECT|*
*|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|*
    *|ARCHIVE|*
*|END:IF|*
*|FACEBOOK:PROFILEURL|*
*|TWITTER:PROFILEURL|*
*|FORWARD|*
*|IF:REWARDS*
    *|REWARDS|*
*|END:IF|*
```

Using this PHP function and regex i can get the results of all the tags

```
preg_match_all("/\*\|(.*?)\|\*/", $this->template, $elements);
    $this->elements["Tags"] = $elements[0];
    $this->elements["TagNames"] = $elements[1];
```

What i want, is to find a way to capture the IF:(TAG) statements and IFNOT:(TAG) statements as well and the content.

What i have so far is

```
ergex=> /\*\|IF(([A-Z{0-3}]):([A-Z_]+))\|\*(.*?)\*\|END:IF\|\*|\*\|(.*?)\|\*/g
```

But it only catches the tags them self as a whole, can anyone point me in the right direction or help me out.

Comment: whats the source of this?

Comment: Your first regex already captues plain and IF "template tags". Matching nested groups wouldn't necesarily help with processing. Rather loop through all results in order, and apply logic then. -- Also, yes, how did you come with such a templating mini-language? Writing your own tokenizer and interpreter is a somewhat pointless endavour (seeing the current state of investigations, that is).

Comment: The base approach you are using is too "simplistic", you should take a tokening approach.  You can reference this basic lexer/parser I made for inspiration https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/emptyLexer.php

Comment: I used this for a JSON object parser on another question that version is here: https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/JasonDecoder.php

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments you approach is to simplistic, I can get you started using the method I use for these things.  It's more a tokenizer/lexer/parser methodology.

That sounds big and scary but it actually makes it simpler

```
<?php
function parse($subject, $tokens)
{
    $types = array_keys($tokens);
    $patterns = [];
    $lexer_stream = [];
    $result = false;
    foreach ($tokens as $k=>$v){
        $patterns[] = "(?P<$k>$v)";
    }
    $pattern = "/".implode('|', $patterns)."/i";
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        //print_r($matches);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
            $match = [];
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $match = $matches[$type][$key];
                if (is_array($match) && $match[1] != -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            $tok  = [
                'content' => $match[0],
                'type' => $type,
                'offset' => $match[1]
            ];
            $lexer_stream[] = $tok;
        }
        $result = parseTokens( $lexer_stream );
    }
    return $result;
}

function parseTokens( array &$lexer_stream ){
    $result = [];
    $mode = 'none';
    while($current = current($lexer_stream)){
        $content = $current['content'];
        $type = $current['type'];
        switch($type){
            case 'T_WHITESPACE':
                next($lexer_stream);
            break;
            case 'T_TAG_START': 
                $mode = 'start';
                next($lexer_stream);
            break;
            case 'T_WORD': 
                if($mode == 'start') echo "Tag $content\n";
                if($mode == 'ifnot') echo "IfNot $content\n";
                next($lexer_stream);
            break;
            case 'T_TAG_END': 
                $mode = 'none';
                next($lexer_stream);
            break;
            case 'T_IFNOT':
                $mode = 'ifnot';
                next($lexer_stream);
            break;

            case 'T_EOF': return;

            case 'T_UNKNOWN':
            default:
                print_r($current);
                trigger_error("Unknown token $type value $content", E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    if( !$current ) return;
    print_r($current);
    trigger_error("Unclosed item $mode for $type value $content", E_USER_ERROR);
}

$subject = '*|SUBJECT|*
*|SUBJECT|*
*|IFNOT:ARCHIVE_PAGE|*
    *|ARCHIVE|*
*|END:IF|*
*|FACEBOOK:PROFILEURL|*
*|TWITTER:PROFILEURL|*
*|FORWARD|*
*|IF:REWARDS*
    *|REWARDS|*
*|END:IF|*';

$tokens = [
    'T_WHITESPACE'      => '[\r\n\s\t]+',
    'T_TAG_START'       => '\*\|',
    'T_TAG_END'         => '\|\*',
    'T_IF'              => 'IF:',
    'T_IFNOT'           => 'IFNOT:',    
    'T_ENDIF'           => 'END:IF',
    'T_WORD'            => '\w+',
    'T_EOF'             => '\Z',
    'T_UNKNOWN'         => '.+?'
];

parse($subject,$tokens);
```

So this you can see [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fabce5a420b20b1b9fc12fb82fa14f020b7c271)

And it outputs:

```
Tag SUBJECT
Tag SUBJECT
IfNot ARCHIVE_PAGE
Tag ARCHIVE
Array
(
    [content] => END:IF
    [type] => T_ENDIF
    [offset] => 69
)
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Unknown token T_ENDIF value END:IF in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>67</b><br />
```

The error is because I only worked it out to the `End if` tag (have to leave something for you to do).

For a parser that I did using this for another question you can find that on my github

https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/JasonDecoder.php

It should give you some ideas on how to handle nested array like structures etc..

The basic idea is you can just add one tag at a time, and then do the parsing for that one tag.  You can do as much or as little error checking on different mode types in the wrong place, and so on.  It just gives everything a nice structure to work from.  Essential it works the same basic way you method works, using `preg_match_all` and a string of regx's.  The main difference is that it builds the full regx from an array, and then using the array keys and named capture groups (and a bit of code magic) it lets you reference them in a more intuitive way.  It also uses the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag, which I found to be faster then the other flags.

One note is that the order of the tags is important, if you put the `T_UNKNOWN` tag first it matches everything so it won't go to the tags below it.  Therefor they should be the more specific the match the higher in the list.  For example you could do a tag like this

```
    'T_IFNOT'           => '\*\|IFNOT:',
```

Instead of the one I have, but it would likely have to go before the:

```
    'T_TAG_START'       => '\*\|',
```

Because that tag will match it first.

Also don't forget to put `next($lexer_stream);` or it will be an infinite loop.  It's necessary to use while and next to control the array pointer when in nested structures like arrays.

Good Luck and happy parsing!